# Reading partition/directory /storage/extSdCard as a file, byte by byte. Android

Tags: java, android, file, directory, partition

I've got problem with this code which is working on windows machine with sdcard connected, but wont work on android. Does anyone know how to read sdcard as a single file byte by byte? I'd like to read all bytes from partition.

```
    public void buttonOnClick(View v) throws IOException {
    //File diskRoot = new File("\\\\.\\G:"); // for Windows disk ex. G

    int off=0;
    int len=1024;

    FileInputStream stream = null;

    //TODO find direct access to sd card
    //File sdDir = new File("storage/extSdCard");
    File sdDir = new File("storage/extSdCard");
    //File sdDir = new File("dev/block/platform/s3c-sdhci.2/mmcblk1");
    //File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    //FileInputStream asd = openFileInput(Environment.getExternalStorageState());

    //File sdDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()); gives internal storage of device
    //sdDir.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    //File file = new File(sdDir,"");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try {
        stream = new FileInputStream(sdDir);

        while (stream.read(buffer, off, len) != -1) {
            //
        }
        stream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any of commented above versions of "File sdDir" gives in logcat same output:

```
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/extSdCard: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:78)
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at raf.test.MBR.buttonOnClick(MBR.java:77)
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3719)
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4261)
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17356)
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-01 21:13:06.751  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 21:13:06.756  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 21:13:06.756  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-01 21:13:06.756  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-01 21:13:06.756  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 21:13:06.756  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
01-01 21:13:06.756  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:405)
01-01 21:13:06.756  10887-10887/raf.test W/System.err﹕ ... 16 more
```

Permisions are:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_external_storage"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.write_external_storage"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you will have that kind of access from a standard Android app without root - there are a few things to consider:

1. Android gives you file system access from your application - not raw access to partitions.
2. You typically need to unmount a partition/file system in order to
   access byte-by-byte since you don't want any permissions to get in
   your way and you can only unmount as a root user.
3. If you are root then you can unmount the drive and then issue a
   `dd` command to create a new file with a raw image with something
   like:

   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c dd if=/dev/deviceToRead1> of=rawOutputFile");
4. I can tell you that if this is possible from a non-root device then it will treated
   as a security vulnerability that will be patched ASAP since it would
   put the entire phone and all of the data on it at risk.  If this
   were possible from a non-root device then it would be possible for
   any application to steal/read the data from other applications which
   Android specifically restricts in various ways.
5. This behavior would likely be blocked by the Google Play
   verification process if you plan on putting this app in the Google
   Play store because it is considered malicious.
6. I can also tell you if you can find a way to make this happen then it will require
   an exploit that will give you root permissions.  Once you have root
   (via an exploit) then the rest is easy to do with basic command line
   utilities (`mount` and `dd`, specifically).
7. From a commercial standpoint if this were possible your app would
   put forensic software out of business :)  Keep in mind that forensic
   software that does exactly this procedure also needs raw access to
   the partitions that require physical access to the device and/or
   root access on the device.
8. The reason why you get the `java.io.FileNotFoundException` is
   because you using APIs that give you access on a File System level
   and what you need bypasses file system functionality.  You will
   never have raw access to a partition using file system calls.

I think that this list answers your question.  You won't be able to do it without first getting root otherwise the entire security model of Android would be proven to be useless.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I forgot to mention that i'd like to run it on non root devices. Reffering to the second point i can add other permisions to this app. If you know other way to do this, with any other permision which should be granted (ex. android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS) i'll be waitng for your reply.

Comment: You won't be able to do this without root access since it would break the entire Android security model.  It is possible to do from a non-root application only if that non-root application exploits a vulnerability in Android to escalate privileges to root for the operation to succeed.